# There are two restaurants (one in Saigon, one in Hong Kong) called "全記". Where does that name come from and what does it mean?

Tags: china

Name seen at 0:07
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kyqE2Nq3pc

Second restaurant comes up with a google search for "全記".

Have no idea how to proceed from here.

Comment: I'm not sure this is history; can you review [help] and edit the question to help make it clear why this is in scope for H:SE?

Comment: If StackExchange had an etiology section, I'd be happy to post there.
I'm asking where the shared name of two institutions comes from. I thought that would best fit history. Is there something that excludes it from the scope?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: As the meaning appears to me to clearly be a historical reference, I will support this question as being on topic.

Comment: Does anyone here know a good, not-exclusively-medical etiology forum? My primary interest with history is tracing the origins of existing things (why they are, as opposed to other things, or as opposed to not existing).

Comment: What is the historical reference? H:SE is an English language site and if you speak the site's language, there is no historical reference in the question. Could someone make it explicit for those of us who only speak two or three languaged?

Comment: "if SE had an X section" is  _not_ an excuse for posting out of scope content.  There is nothing in the question that suggests history whatsoever.   (You and Mr. Geerkens seem to be aware of some historical implications that haven't been shared with the rest of us).

Comment: Wouldn't Chinese SE be the logical place to post this question? Without further reserach in the question, I don't see any evidence that this is history.

Comment: Ok, well, I'm trying to find the history of this name as it applies to these institutions. I thought that would make it more history than etymology. Can you tell me how it's not history?

Comment: @StepStart The comment by dROOOze on Pieter Geerkens' answer below suggests one very good reason why this may not be a question about history.

Answer (score 2):

Although [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E5%85%A8%E8%A8%98%0A%0A%E5%85%A8%0A%0A%E8%A8%98) renders the full phrase as "*Full note*" it renders the individual ideograms as respectively "*all*" and "*remember*".

This to me sounds very familiar to the [official motto of the  Province of Quebec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_me_souviens):

"*Je me souviens*" - "*I remember*"

> It may be paraphrased as conveying the meaning
>
> > We do not forget, and will never forget, our ancient lineage, traditions and memories of all the past.

In both Saigon and Hong Kong this would seem to be a reminiscence for the old colonial rule of respectively the French (or perhaps pre-1976 independence of South Vietnam) and the British.

Comment: The [suffix 記](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A8%98#Definitions) is commonly used in the title of shops and restaurants. If the shop's owner [has the last name 全](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%A8#Definitions), then 全記 just means *The* 全 *(Family) restaurant*.